# Ruby on Rails - how do I select which data I want to render from seed.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a seed.rb file in my rails app which contains 151 objects.

In my .html file I'm able to render ALL my objects in the seed.rb file.

```
  <tbody>
    <% @pokemon.each do |pokemon| %>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6">
          <a href="/pokemon/<%=pokemon.no%>"><%= pokemon.name %></a>
          <br>
          <%= pokemon.no %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

**How do I render ONE object or a specific object?**

Here's an example of my seed data:

pokemon = Pokemon.create({ no: '001', name: 'Bulbasaur' })

pokemon = Pokemon.create({ no: '002', name: 'Ivysaur' })

pokemon = Pokemon.create({ no: '003', name: 'Venusayr' })

Comment: can you check the `no` attribute?

Comment: @AwladLiton You mean use the "no" attribute to render what I want specifically? What is the proper erb syntax to do that?

Comment: search with `no` attribute for specific object in the `@pokemon`.

Comment: @AwladLiton Sorry, perhaps I should've been more clear. I have a page that currently renders all 151 seed data. However it appears as a list since I'm asking erb to show all. I really want to customize the page so it looks like a grid via css/bootstrap. I'm asking how to specifically render one object from the seed data so i can use bootstrap to make the page look like a grid of data instead of a list.

Comment: note: 'no' is a bad name for the attribute which actually means the number. 'number' is better for readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to render just one instance? If so you just need to use basic ruby in your controller to get one instance. Open a rails console and run

```
Pokemon.count
```

You should see the total number of records saved.  In the controller set the instance variable

```
@pokemon = Pokemon.first
@pokemon = Pokemon.last
Pokemon.find(n) # where n equals the id of the instance you want to display
```

However your question sounds like you want to display all the instances and use bootstrap to display them in a grid. You're already getting all the instances and looping through them. You'll need to read up on bootstrap to employ the different classes to get the desired look.

In your current code, @pokemon is an array holding the results of the active record call Pokemon.all which means in the view you can use

```
@pokemon.first
```

to display one instance. Though, this would not be a very efficient way of doing things.

Comment: Thank you Margo for the detailed explanation! 

Using <%= @pokemon.first.name %> does indeed print out "Bulbasaur" in my view.